# Some keys are invalid on emacs when using German keyboard

Tags: kde, keyboard, emacs

When I am using emacs 23.3 on KDE, I can not input `^`, `´` and `~` from my German keyboard. If I press these keys, then emacs says that `<dead-circumflex>`, `<dead-acute>` and `<dead-tilde>` are undefined.

I can input `^`, `´` and `~` on other applications (e.g. Konsole, Kwrite and firefox), and I can also paste these letters on emacs.

I have tried to [type C-x ret C-\ latin-1-postfix](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2009-08/msg00038.html), but there is no change.

Could anyone tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know what's causing this problem or how to fix this, but I can offer a workaround for most purposes.

Normally, dead keys are processed at a very low input layer, not even visible from Lisp. But you can do the processing in Lisp.

#### If you want the keys to act as dead keys:

There is already a limited mechanism for dead keys in Lisp, designed for 8-bit character sets on machines that don't have any way to input non-ASCII characters. If you type `C-x 8` followed by an accent and a letter, the corresponding accented letter is inserted, thanks to the [`iso-transl` library](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Unibyte-Mode.html#index-dead-character-1479). We can copy this mechanism. Put this in your `.emacs`:

```
(define-key key-translation-map [dead-grave] (lookup-key key-translation-map "\C-x8`"))
(define-key key-translation-map [dead-acute] (lookup-key key-translation-map "\C-x8'"))
(define-key key-translation-map [dead-circumflex] (lookup-key key-translation-map "\C-x8^"))
(define-key key-translation-map [dead-diaeresis] (lookup-key key-translation-map "\C-x8\""))
(define-key key-translation-map [dead-tilde] (lookup-key key-translation-map "\C-x8~"))
(define-key isearch-mode-map [dead-grave] nil)
(define-key isearch-mode-map [dead-acute] nil)
(define-key isearch-mode-map [dead-circumflex] nil)
(define-key isearch-mode-map [dead-diaeresis] nil)
(define-key isearch-mode-map [dead-tilde] nil)
```

The map [`key-translation-map`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Translation-Keymaps.html#index-key_002dtranslation_002dmap-1542) rewrites key sequences as they are entered, so this will make <kbd>dead `</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> equivalent to <kbd>à</kbd> for most purposes. Explicitly setting entries in `isearch-mode-map` to `nil` is necessary because otherwise pressing a dead key would exit isearch before the translation could kick in.

#### If you want the accent characters to be inserted immediately

```
(define-key key-translation-map [dead-grave] "`")
(define-key key-translation-map [dead-acute] "'")
(define-key key-translation-map [dead-circumflex] "^")
(define-key key-translation-map [dead-diaeresis] "\"")
(define-key key-translation-map [dead-tilde] "~")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. The above settings allow me to input all of ^, ´ and ~ on emacs by pressing "^ SPC", "´ SPC" and "~ SPC". Do you know if there is a way to input these letters by pressing only each key (i.e. without SPC)? I have tried to modify the above settings like "(define-key key-translation-map [dead-circumflex] (lookup-key key-translation-map "\C-x8^SPC"))", but this seems to be invalid.

Comment: @moduli: If you want to press only one key for these characters everywhere (not just in Emacs), you can change the keyboard settings in KDE. Choose a keyboard with something like "German - no dead keys" ("ohne Akzenttasten").

Comment: @moduli Oh, I think I misunderstood your question. I thought you wanted `^`, `\`` and `~` to be dead keys, and that wasn't working. If you want them to insert the actual character, then it's even easier: `(define-key key-translation-map [dead-tilde] "~")` and the like. But in that case it may be better to handle this at the system level (through KDE) as elmicha suggests.

Comment: @elmicha Thank you for your comment. I can input the letters by one press for all applications expect firefox and emacs. For firefox, I can input ^ by two presses the same key and I do not think that is a problem.

Comment: @Gilles Thank you for the setting. It works as I expected!

Answer (score 5):

try adding `(require 'iso-transl)` in your `.emacs` file.
See also:

- [Problem with "dead-acute" | help-gnu-emacs](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2009-05/msg00167.html)
- [Re: Problem with "dead-acute" | help-gnu-emacs](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2009-05/msg00179.html)

Comment: This makes the keys not dead.